# why isn't link working when I use it with components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying use link to make a link for each page section in the header to go to that specific page when it is clicked, the problem is that it isn't working when I put the link portion in the headers and pages.

in App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";
import Header from "./pages/Header";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Resume from "./pages/Resume";
import Projects from "./pages/projects";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Card from "./card/card";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <About />
      <Resume />
      <Card
        img={require("./img/resume.png")}
        title="Resume"
        description=""
        button="download"
        button2 = "view"
      />
      <Projects />
      <Contact/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

in Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <body class="min-h-screen bg-orange-100 p-10 ">
        <div className="App" class="font-inter">
          <div class="p-5">
            <h1 class="text-8xl  text-yellow-900">***</h1>
            <h2 class="indent-20 text-4xl text-yellow-900   ">
             ****
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="pl-20 space-y-4">
            <div class="p-5">
              <h1 class="text-4xl text-yellow-900">Links:</h1>
              <div class="  indent-12 text-3xl text-yellow-700">
                <h2>Github</h2>
                <h2>LinkedIn</h2>
                <h2>Behanced</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to="#contact">
                <h1 class="  text-4xl text-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-800">
                  Contact:
                </h1>
              </Link>
              <div class="p-1 indent-12 text-3xl text-yellow-700 ">
                <h2> ****** </h2>
                <h2 class="p-1.5"> *** </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to="#about">
                <h1 class="text-4xl text-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-800">
                  About Me
                </h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to="#resume">
                <h1 class="  text-4xl text-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-800">
                  Resume
                </h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to="#projects">
                <h1 class="  text-4xl text-yellow-900 hover:text-yellow-800">
                  Projects:
                </h1>
              </Link>
              <div class="pt-2 indent-12 text-3xl text-yellow-700">
                <h2>Link-Tree Style Website</h2>
                <h2>Calulator</h2>
                <h2>Static Portfolio Website</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

In Contact.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Contact() {
  return (
    <section id="contact">
      <body class="min-h-screen bg-orange-100 p-10">
        <div className="App" class="font-inter p-5">
          <h1 class="text-7xl  text-yellow-900"> Contact </h1>
          <div>
            <p class=" pt-[1rem] pl-[6rem] absolute w-[50rem]  text-4xl text-yellow-900"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I tried adding the link portion the app.js portion of my code but that didn't work either and I tried adding Link and BrowserRouter from react-router-dom. I only tried with the contact portion.

Comment: You are not using `Routes` and `Route`.

Answer (score 0):

as i check your question you want to move particular section of next page using link. Try with this code-

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/PATH_NAME", hash: "#first" }></Link>
```

In the above code hash is your div id.. Please try this code, if it doesn't work just lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks